# c++ Inline ASM, 'asm' operand has impossimble constraints

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

it might be a dump question, but I don't figure out why my code doesn't compile.

It's my first experience with inlined ASM, and I try to write a 16-byte unaligned version of  `memcpy`

So, this is my code:

```
void* memcpy16u(void* dest, void* src, size_t count) {
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
        ".loop:\n\t"
        "movdqu     xmm0, [rsi]\n\t"
        "movdqu     [rdi], xmm0\n\t"
        "lea        rsi, [rsi + 16]\n\t"
        "lea        rdi, [rdi + 16]\n\t"
        "sub        rcx, 16\n\t"
        "cmp        rcx, 0\n\t"
        "jg     .loop\n\t"
        ".att_syntax prefix\n\t"
        :
        :"S"(src), "D"(dest), "c"(count)
        :"rcx", "rdi", "rsi"
    );

    return dest;
}
```

I compile this like `g++ memcpy.cpp -o memcpy`

And compiler said

```
asm operand has impossible constraints
);
 ^
```

So, can anyone explain where's a mistake? And I'll be glad if you give me some tips about implementation

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this task actually require that you use assembly instructions?

Comment: @Xirema Yes, it's the task from assembly course

Comment: what are you expecting `:"S"(src), "D"(dest), "c"(count)` to do here?

Comment: Are you allowed to write a pure assembly language file?  IMHO, this is easier than having to work with the inline assembly interface.

Comment: @Claies I expect that `src` pointer will be written to `rsi` register, `dest` to `rdi` and `count` to `rcx`
There is an example like this
http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: @ThomasMatthews unfortunatelly, I'm not allowed to do that in another way

Comment: You are not allowed to clobber an operand. Use a dummy output instead.  In this case you can use a read-write operand too, since your operands are locals that are pass by value anyway. Also do not switch assembly styles behind the compiler's back as that won't always work. If you want intel syntax use `-masm=intel`. PS: the `cmp rcx, 0` is not needed since `sub` sets the flags.

Comment: @Jester so, can you point out, where's the mistake exactly? Where I clobber an  operand?

Comment: You know the last line is called the clobber list, right? This one `:"rcx", "rdi", "rsi"`. All of those are input operands you are not allowed to list them. If you want to change them, you need to use a dummy output or a read-write operand.

Comment: @Jester yeah, it seems that this is the mistake, thank you!

Comment: @Jester sorry for that, but maybe you can say something about implementation? Now it works, but, as expected, always coppies `16*n` bytes. So, what is the best way to copy exactly `count` bytes? (Yeah, I know I can just still copy by 1 byte when `rcx` become less than 16, but I'm not sure that this is the best way)

Comment: You can finish off with a `rep movsb`

Comment: @Jester Yeah, thank you, now it works fine

Comment: @Jester: ugh, that's a terrible suggestion for performance, on CPUs before IceLake adds the small-ERMSB feature to reduce startup overhead. Much better to do an unaligned final vector that potentially overlaps, copying the last 16 bytes of the input to the last 16 bytes of the output. (But you need a different strategy for copies where the total size is less than 16, e.g. `movq` or 8-byte integer `mov`.  glibc's memcpy does that for copy sizes of 1, 2..3, 4..7, 8..15, 16..31.  See comments in https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S.html#19).

Comment: Or for a simple version, falling back to a byte-at-a-time loop when the total size is under 16 bytes wouldn't be terrible.  But @NikitaVoloshin: your loop won't even run at 1 iteration per clock because you do so much work with pointer increments and loop counters (http://agner.org/optimize/).  e.g. you can omit the `cmp` because `sub` already sets flags that way.  And don't forget a `"memory"` clobber, or dummy input/output operands to tell gcc which memory you modify.  `asm volatile` doesn't tell the optimizer about the side-effect of dereferencing the pointer operands.

Comment: Of course on top of all that has been mentioned you are just passing the addresses through the operands `:"S"(src), "D"(dest)` the compiler may not even realize all the data into memory before executing the inline assembly. The quickest but leat efficient mechanism would be to add `"memory"` to the clobber list.